# Javascript NiceEdit Configuration

Tags: javascript, jquery, nicedit

I'm trying to use [nicedit](http://nicedit.com)

Currently I'm using this to add nicedit to all text areas:

```
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
```

How do I configure these wysiwygs? I found I can configure single boxes by:

```
new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}).panelInstance('area2');
```

But how do I do this when using `bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);` ?

I'm baffled.

Thanks!

For what it's worth, We also have jquery running as well.

Comment: Did you find a solution? The documentation isn't very clear on this. I tried this but no luck: `bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas( new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}) ) });`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the right answer to question...
This is really missing in the documentation of NicEdit. 
With this is possible to configure all textareas with the same custom config.

```
   bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
      nicEditors.allTextAreas({buttonList : ['bold','italic','underline']});
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

download nicedit-latest.js and use it.

in nicedit-latest.js find

```
if(type&&(hasButton||this.ne.options.fullPanel))
```

(it is somewhere on line 40.)

than delete it and its brackets

```
{ }
```

but not this line between the brackets

```
this.panelButtons.push(new type(this.panelElm,buttonName,options,this.ne));if(!hasButton){this.buttonList.push(buttonName)}
```

save and try again. all textareas will have the full panel :)